# Pandas - get last n values from a group with an offset.

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, datetime, group-by

I have data frame (`pandas`,`python3.5`) with date as index.
The `electricity_use` is the label I should predict.
e.g.

```
          City Country  electricity_use
DATE                                   
7/1/2014     X       A             1.02
7/1/2014     Y       A             0.25
7/2/2014     X       A             1.21
7/2/2014     Y       A             0.27
7/3/2014     X       A             1.25
7/3/2014     Y       A             0.20
7/4/2014     X       A             0.97
7/4/2014     Y       A             0.43
7/5/2014     X       A             0.54
7/5/2014     Y       A             0.45
7/6/2014     X       A             1.33
7/6/2014     Y       A             0.55
7/7/2014     X       A             2.01
7/7/2014     Y       A             0.21
7/8/2014     X       A             1.11
7/8/2014     Y       A             0.34
7/9/2014     X       A             1.35
7/9/2014     Y       A             0.18
7/10/2014    X       A             1.22
7/10/2014    Y       A             0.27
```

Of course the data is larger. 
My goal is to create to each row the last 3 `electricity_use` on the group (`'City' 'country'`), with gap of 5 days (i.e. - to take the last first 3 values from 5 days back). the dates can be non-consecutive, but they are ordered. 
For example, to the two last rows the result should be:

```
          City Country  electricity_use prev_1 prev_2 prev_3
DATE                                                        
7/10/2014    X       A             1.22   0.54   0.97   1.25
7/10/2014    Y       A             0.27   0.45   0.43   0.20
```

because the date is `7/10/2014`, and the gap is `5 days`, so we start looking  from `7/5/2014` and those are the 3 last values from this date, to each group (in this case, the groups are `(X,A)` and `(Y,A)`.

I implemented in with a loop that is going over each group, but I have a feeling it could be done in a much more efficient way.

Comment: It should be possible to do this by shifting or offsetting the date and then merging or joining on the shifted Date, City and Country to get the other column values.

Comment: @Matts, can you write a code that is doing that?

Comment: @BinyaminEven I could probably figure it out if I spent the time to do it, but it's not something I could do easily.

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach to do this would be to reindex your dataframe and iteratively merge n times

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

# make sure index is in datetime format
df['index'] = df.index
df1 = df.copy()

for i in range(3):
    df1['index'] = df['index'] - timedelta(5+i)
    df = df1.merge(df,left_on=['City','Country','date'],right_on=['City','Country','date'],how='left',suffixes=('','_'+str(i)))
```

A faster approach would be to use shift by and remove bogus values

```
df['date'] = df.index

df.sort_values(by=['City','Country','date'],inplace=True)

temp = df[['City','Country','date']].groupby(['City','Country']).first()

# To pick the oldest date of every city + country group

df.merge(temp,left_on=['City','Country'],right_index=True,suffixes=('','_first'))

df['diff_date'] = df['date'] - df['date_first']

df.diff_date = [int(i.days) for i in df['diff_date']]

# Do a shift by 5
for i range(5,8):
    df['days_prior_'+str(i)] = df['electricity_use'].shift(i)
# Top i values for every City + Country code would be bogus values as they would be values of the group prior to it
    df.loc[df['diff_date'] < i,'days_prior_'+str(i)] = 0
```